# What are the main ideas and goals in the Queen's Indian Defense?

Tags: opening, strategy, theory, 1.d4, queens-indian

There's no real surprise when it comes to the strategy for the King's Indian Defence: storm white's king side, maybe sac a few things, and mate (ideally).

But what does a practitioner of the QID hope to achieve in terms of the opening and long term goals?

`1. d4 Nf6 2. c4 e6 3. Nc3 b6`

Comment: The Queen's Indian is usually reached via `3.Nf3 b6`. You've included the moves `3.Nc3 b6` instead, but while this *could* transpose to a QID, it probably shouldn't, because in this move order Black has done nothing to prevent `4.e4`. The QID often gets paired with the Nimzo-Indian in repertoires. In response to `3.Nc3`, the Nimzo comes out via `3...Bb4`. And when White instead plays `3.Nf3` (sometimes specifically to avoid the Nimzo), then Black heads into the QID with `3...b6`.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The key ideas for Black in the `Queen's Indian Defense` is to:

- Restrain White in the center
- Quick Development

The `Queen's Indian Defense` can be reached after the moves:

```
    [FEN ""]
    1. d4 Nf6 2. c4 e6 3. Nf3 b6
```

In the `Queen's Indian Defense`, black is going aim his light-squared bishop and knight at `e4` in order to restrain the moves `e4` and to prevent `d4 to d5`.

White's most popular move is `4...g3` in which white aims to complete development on the king side and counter black on the long diagonal.

A key position is reached after the following:

```
    [FEN ""]
    1. d4 Nf6 2. c4 e6 3. Nf3 b6 4. g3 Bb7 5. Bg2 Be7 6. O-O O-O 7. Nc3
```

In the above position, `7...d5` might seem like a logical move, but it is against the spirit of the opening which say's that Black should be waiting for the most opportune moment to make moves like `7...d5` which occupy the center until the timing is just right. Also, after exchanging pawns on  `d5`, black finds himself with 2 problems, the bishop on `b7` is blocked in and the `c pawn` is on an open file and becomes vulnerable to attack.  For example, after white plays `Bf4` to eye the `c pawn`, Black would like to move his pawn to `c5`, but after the following:

```
    [FEN ""]
    1. d4 Nf6 2. c4 e6 3. Nf3 b6 4. g3 Bb7 5. Bg2 Be7 6. O-O O-O 7. Nc3 d5 8. cxd5 exd5  
    9. Bf4 c5 10. dxc5 bxc5
```

The above leaves Black with a hanging pawn formation. The d and c pawns are extremely vulnerable and if white can quickly generate an attack such as `11. Ne5` generating a third attacker and pinning the pawn.  Black may continue `11...Na6` and now white has `12. Nc4` taking advantage of the pin with the mindset of getting his knight to `e3`, so Black often plays `Qd7`, but White just plays `Na5`

Going back to positon after `7. Nc3`, we just illustrated that `7...d5` is not a logical move for black, so instead he plays `7...Ne4` directly occupying the `e4` square making it impossible for white to play `e4` and he wants to use his `f pawn` to strengthen his hold over the `e4` square and he won't block the diagonal of his bishop.  After the following:

```
    [FEN ""]
    1. d4 Nf6 2. c4 e6 3. Nf3 b6 4. g3 Bb7 5. Bg2 Be7 6. O-O O-O 7. Nc3 Ne4 
    8. Nxe4 Bxe4 9. Ne1 Bxg2 10. Nxg2 d5
```

Black is now willing to play `d5` because there is not bishop on `b7` anymore and he can now gain share of the center and the position is about equal, so after `7...Ne4`, white often plays `8. Qc2`, `8...f5` looks like a natural response, but white plays `9. Ne5` and would black would quickly find himself in trouble after:

```
    [FEN ""]
    1. d4 Nf6 2. c4 e6 3. Nf3 b6 4. g3 Bb7 5. Bg2 Be7 6. O-O O-O 7. Nc3 Ne4 
    8. Qc2 f5 9. Ne5 d6 10. Nxe4 fxe4 11. Bxe4
```

In the above diagram, black does not have time to capture the `knight` because of the `bishop` and `queen` staring down the diagonal, so instead of `8...f5`, black should play `8...Nxc3 9. Qxc3 f5`.  White still has in mind one other factor to gain an advantage.  In addition to still play pawn to `e4`, he also counts on the fact that blacks `e6` pawn will become weak if black plays `d6` eventually, so for example:

```
    [FEN ""]
    1. d4 Nf6 2. c4 e6 3. Nf3 b6 4. g3 Bb7 5. Bg2 Be7 6. O-O O-O 7. Nc3 Ne4 
    8. Qc2 Nxc3 9. Qxc3 f5 10. b3 Bf6 11. Bb2 d6 12. Rad1 Qe7 13. Ne1 Bxg2 14. Nxg2 Nd7 
   15. Qc2.
```

White is looking for small small initiative based upon the weakness of the `e6` pawn, so in the end the fight for `e4` is the major theme that holds the entire `Queen's Indian` together.

Answer (score 0):

The main advantage of the Queen's Indian defense is that it gives a good development to the light squared bishop, otherwise Black's problem piece, along the long diagonal.

Because it involves a "slow" development, it gives White a chance to overreach.

For the above reasons, it was a favorite opening of (then) World Champion, J.R. Capablanca (nearly a century ago).